# React Native - Customize date format using Moment.js

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I am using moment.js to get the current date, however I am having a problem about the date formatting and I don't have any idea on how to customize it since I am just new using it.

By the way I used this.

```
moment().format('LLLL');
```

My expected output is:

```
Mmmm-dd-yyyy hh:mmAM/PM (Timezone) or just like Sep-19-2020 3:00AM (GMT +8)
```

Is the any other way to achieve this?

Comment: It depends on the date that you're using, what is it like? It can have lots of types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
moment().locale('tr').format("MMM-DD-yyyy h:mA [(GMT] Z[)]")
moment().locale('en_US').format("MMM-DD-yyyy h:mA [(GMT] Z[)]")
```

If you want to use locale in React Native.

instead

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

you should use this

```
import 'moment/min/moment-with-locales'
moment.locale('tr');
moment().format("MMM-DD-yyyy h:mA [(GMT] Z[)]");
```

- The things you write in square brackets are written directly. that is, they are escape characters.